# A Problem dealing with Sampling

Tags: probability, statistics

Please consider the following problem and the solution to it. Is the solution
right? I think the question is ambiguous.

Bob

Problem:

A company producing solid metal rods takes a random sample of $30$ rods from
each shipment and measure the diameter of metal rods. Using the mean values of
these samples a sampling distribution was constructed, which has a mean value
of $1$ cm, and a standard deviation of $0.1$ cm. What is the probability that
a shipment of metal rods will have a mean value of diameter between $0.7$ cm
and $1.3$ cm?

Answer:

Assuming the distribution of the diameter of metal rods is normal, we are asking
what is the probability that we are going to be within three standard
deviations of the mean, which is $0.9912$.

Comment: looks correct to me :)

Comment: If you are finding a CI for the mean of a shipment, then you need to know how many items are in the shipment. Is that the ambiguity you are concerned about?

Comment: The question is too imprecise to admit an answer

Comment: I am confused by what the standard deviation of 0.1 cm means. Is that computed by taking each rod in the sample or is it a measure of the variance of the samples. I am thinking it is the first. If it is the first then I am thinking my answer is wrong. Also, I am thinking that you are suppose to assume that each shipment has 30 rods but that is not a good assumption in the real world. In the real world, if I ordered a 1 cm metal rod and I got a metal rod of only 0.8 cm I would be unhappy.